# make bitmaps tag a synonym of bitmap

Tags: support, synonym-request

The [bitmaps](/questions/tagged/bitmaps) tag seems completely redundant, but there are 101 questions marked with it. I suggest making it a synonym of [bitmap](/questions/tagged/bitmap) which has more questions (5016) and covers the same topic.

Small differences between those two can occur in case of questions which require several bitmaps processed/compared/etc. (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558107/quickest-way-to-compare-two-bitmapimages-to-check-if-they-are-different-in-wpf-c)) but I think this is negligible and these two tags should be merged anyway.